# ngx-translate sometimes not load json on init

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I have an angular application with 3 languages: Spanish, English and Catalan. The app is deployed in Production,and we are facing a very weird issue: some users navigators (either chrome, firefox or edge) don't load the `json` with the keys in the default language.

The normal behaviour is this: when a user enter to the app, one of the calls is this:

[image: Normal behaviour]

were we can see that the `json` is loaded well. But some users don't have that initial call, and it's very weird:
[image: wrong behaviour]

But, if you switch to another language and then select the default language, it works, and it load all the available languages.

The code is this:

`app.module.ts`

```js
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/es';
import localeEn from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import localeCa from '@angular/common/locales/ca';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

registerLocaleData(localeEs, 'es');
registerLocaleData(localeEn, 'en');
registerLocaleData(localeCa, 'ca');

const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  {
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useValue: 'es-ES',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => {
          return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
        },
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
      isolate: false,
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

  ],
  providers: [APP_PROVIDERS],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The component that change the language:

```js
export class I18nComboComponent implements OnInit {
  activeLang: I18NLanguage;

  allLangs: I18NLanguage[];

  language: UntypedFormControl = new UntypedFormControl(null);

  constructor(private i18nService: I18nLanguagesService, private translateService: TranslateService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allLangs = this.i18nService.getLanguages();
    const lang: I18NLanguage = this.allLangs.find(ln => ln.countryCodeDosLetras === navigator.language.split('-')[0]);
    if (lang) {
      this.activeLang = lang;
      this.translateService.use(lang.countryCode);
    } else {
      this.activeLang = this.i18nService.getDefaultLang();
    }
    this.language.setValue(this.activeLang.countryCodeDosLetras);
    this.i18nService.setActiveLang(this.activeLang);

    this.language.valueChanges.subscribe(language => {
      this.activeLang = this.allLangs.find(ln => ln.countryCodeDosLetras === language);
      this.translateService.use(this.activeLang.countryCode);
      this.i18nService.setActiveLang(this.activeLang);
    });
  }
}
```

I cannot found a reason for this behaviour. I test it in a bunch of computers and it works like a charm, but some users are getting this.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well what if browser's defaultLang is not one of those 3?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? Also what is your angular version. PS: i am also facing the same issue only the API response code is 301 instead of 304...